# Weird error while sending request to YouTube API PHP

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-analytics-api

I am currently working on a back-end processing that requests channel analytics info back from YouTube Analytics API on PHP. For some reason, I keep receiving a weird error message in:

```
foreach ($metrics as $metric) {
$api = $analytics->reports->query($id, $start_date, $end_date, $metric, $optparams);
print('reached');
    foreach ($api->rows as $r) {
        print($r[0]);
        print($r[1]);
    }
}

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_merge(): Argument #2 must be of type array, string given in ...
```

So I assumed that the error is associated with `$query` and the input should be of type array so I did that:

```
foreach ($metrics as $metric) {
$params = [$id, $start_date, $end_date, $metric, $optparams];
$api = $analytics->reports->query($params);
print('reached');
    foreach ($api->rows as $r) {
        print($r[0]);
        print($r[1]);
    }
}

Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Exception: (query) unknown parameter: '0'
```

But as you can see an error still remains. For the second one, I am assuming since arrays in PHP are technically order maps, that is why it is concerted about '0' but I am still confused why it would ask for an array if it can't process it.

For more context regarding my code, I am using Google API's client library for PHP which I obtained with `composer require google/apiclient:^2.0` . Here is my whole code file where I instantiate all the objects:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  // Set the access token on the client.
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  // Create an authorized analytics service object.
  $analytics = new Google_Service_YouTubeAnalytics($client);

} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/Analytics_Dashboard/oauth2callbackYouTube.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

// here we set some params
$id = '////////';
$end_date = date("Y-m-d"); 
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-30 days"));
$optparams = array(
    'dimensions' => '7DayTotals',
    'sort' => 'day',
);

$metrics = array(
    'views',
    'estimatedMinutesWatched',
    'averageViewDuration',
    'comments',
    'favoritesAdded',
    'favoritesRemoved',
    'likes',
    'dislikes',
    'shares',
    'subscribersGained',
    'subscribersLost'
);

$api_response = $metrics;

// You can only get one metric at a time, so we loop
foreach ($metrics as $metric)
{
    $params = [$id, $start_date, $end_date, $metric, $optparams];
    $api = $analytics->reports->query($params);
    // if (isset($api['rows'])) $api_response[$metric] = $api['rows'][0][0];
    print('reached');
    foreach ($api->rows as $r) {
        print($r[0]);
        print($r[1]);
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help from people who had experience interacting with YouTube Analytics API using PHP! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if this will work, but what if you use an associative array instead of a regular one?

```
    $params = [$id, $start_date, $end_date, $metric, $optparams]; //OLD
    $params = [ 
       'id' => $id, 
       'start_date' => $start_date, 
       'end_date' => $end_date, 
       'metric' => $metric, 
       'opt_params' => $optparams
     ];
```

In case it worked, you would like to use [compact](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php), just for a shorter syntax:

```
    $params = compact('id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'metric', 'opt_params');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am still receiving a similar error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Exception: (query) unknown parameter: 'id' in...` so I am not really sure how to go about it and what kind of input this method expects.

Comment: It's because the documentation does not have an `id` field but an `ids`. At least, that's what's shown in this url :https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query?apix=true
It either has an `opt_params` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters array must include the key values.
You should send a Parameters Array like this:

```
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTubeAnalytics($client);

$queryParams = array(
                    'startDate' => '2016-05-01',
                    'endDate' => '2016-06-30',
                    'metrics' => 'views',
                    'ids' => 'channel==MINE'
                    );


$report = $youtube->reports->query( $queryParams );
```

For more insights on how each parameter needs to be formatted, chekc the [documentation of the parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query#Parameters).